# GraphicsBuffer's GetData always returning 0s

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to clone a mesh using GraphicsBuffer because its read/write option is false, and I can't change that. This is my current code:

```
public static bool Run(Mesh sourceMesh, out Mesh generatedMesh)
{
    GraphicsBuffer sourceDataBuffer = sourceMesh.GetVertexBuffer(0);
    GraphicsBuffer sourceIndexBuffer = sourceMesh.GetIndexBuffer();

    var vertexCount = sourceDataBuffer.count;
    var indexCount = sourceIndexBuffer.count;

    byte[] sourceData = new byte[vertexCount * (sourceDataBuffer.stride / sizeof(byte))];
    byte[] sourceIndex = new byte[(int)(indexCount * ((float)sourceIndexBuffer.stride / sizeof(byte)))];

    sourceDataBuffer.GetData(sourceData);
    sourceIndexBuffer.GetData(sourceIndex);

    var attributes = sourceMesh.GetVertexAttributes();

    generatedMesh = new Mesh();
    generatedMesh.vertexBufferTarget |= GraphicsBuffer.Target.Raw;

    generatedMesh.SetVertexBufferParams(vertexCount, attributes);
    generatedMesh.SetVertexBufferData(sourceData, 0, 0, sourceData.Length);
    generatedMesh.SetIndexBufferParams(indexCount, sourceMesh.indexFormat);
    generatedMesh.SetIndexBufferData(sourceIndex, 0, 0, sourceIndex.Length);

    generatedMesh.subMeshCount = sourceMesh.subMeshCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceMesh.subMeshCount; i++)
    {
        var subMeshDescriptor = sourceMesh.GetSubMesh(i);
        generatedMesh.SetSubMesh(i, subMeshDescriptor);
    }

    sourceDataBuffer.Release();
    sourceIndexBuffer.Release();

    generatedMesh.RecalculateBounds();

    return true; // No error
}
```

It works like a charm in my test project. But when I try to clone things in my main project, `GetData(sourceData)` and `GetData(sourceIndex)` both return arrays of 0s. What could be causing that? Could it be because of the read/write being disabled?

**Edit:** The problem only happens in bundles with non-readable meshes. I thought GraphicsBuffer should work with them, but it doesn't.

Comment: Did `GetData(sourceIndex)` return an array of 0s too?

Comment: @shingo Good question! Yes, it did

Comment: If the mesh is good, maybe this is because it has not been loaded by the GPU yet. (e.g. a mesh in a prefab)

Comment: @shingo Unfortunately that is not the case. I'm picking the mesh from an instantiated game object in the scene. I've updated the question with an error that I'm getting, after replacing GetData with AsyncGPUReadback.Request. Maybe it's related to the problem

Comment: Have you tried to call [`UploadMeshData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.UploadMeshData.html) first?

Comment: @shingo yes, apparently it only works to set read/write to false, not the other way around. Nothing happens when I call it